# Representing events in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have events represented like this:

```
event = {
  "properties": {
    "http.requestMethod": "POST",
    "http.userAgent": "wget",
    "device.product": "ASA",
    "device.vendor": "Cisco"
  }
}
```

I would like to represent and validate these events using pydantic, but I am required to split all of the different namespaces into their own classes like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Http(BaseModel):
    http_requestmethod = Field(alias="http.requestMethod")
    http_useragent = Field(alias="http.userAgent")


class Device(BaseModel):
    device_product = Field(alias="device.product")
    device_vendor = Field(alias="device.vendor")
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you want to get as a result, but, for example,  one of the cases may look like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator

event = {
    "properties": {
        "http.requestMethod": "POST",
        "http.userAgent": "wget",
        "device.product": "ASA",
        "device.vendor": "Cisco"
    }
}


class Http(BaseModel):
    http_requestmethod: str = Field(..., alias="http.requestMethod")
    http_useragent: str = Field(..., alias="http.userAgent")


class Device(BaseModel):
    device_product: str = Field(..., alias="device.product")
    device_vendor: str = Field(..., alias="device.vendor")


class Properties(BaseModel):
    http: Http
    device: Device


class Event(BaseModel):
    properties: Properties

    @validator('properties', pre=True)
    def prop_validator(v):
        return Properties(http=Http(**v).dict(by_alias=True),
                          device=Device(**v).dict(by_alias=True))
```